# Remote Desktop cannot connect to Ubuntu xfce4

Tags: xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

I am trying to get a desktop environment up and running on my ubuntu system running with WSL2 on Windows 11. I ran these commands in ubuntu to get everything installed:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt-get purge xrdp
sudo apt install -y xrdp
sudo apt install -y xfce4
sudo apt install -y xfce4-goodies

sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bak
sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
sudo sed -i 's/max_bpp=32/#max_bpp=32\nmax_bpp=128/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
sudo sed -i 's/xserverbpp=24/#xserverbpp=24\nxserverbpp=128/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession

sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
!comment these lines to:
#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession

!add these lines:
# xfce
startxfce4

sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

After this, I tried connecting to localhost:3390 on Remote Desktop, but it cannot connect.

I tried making sure ubuntu, xrdp, and xfce4 were all up to date. No matter what I try, nothing can be found on port 3390. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble connecting via remote desktop, the article in the comments has a typo which does not update the port correctly:
Try the command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3398/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

You command has an error trying to replace 3389 (not 3398) with 3390.
Try the provided command in this comment and rerun the start command.